# Conditional log apache

Tags: apache, logging

I'm trying to do conditional logging in Apache.
Actually I have this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/assets/.* asset
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/cron/.* cron
CustomLog /var/log/apache/assets.log common env=asset
CustomLog /var/log/apache/cron.log common env=cron
#CustomLog /var/log/apache/access.log combined "expr=(env=!asset && env=!cron)"
```

I'd like the last commented line to log everithing else but "asset" and "cron". Now this configuration give me an error and have no idea, basing on docs, how to construct the "expr".
If I use

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache/access.log combined env=!asset
```

then I'm logging ALL except asset but I want to log ALL except asset AND cron
Cannot do tests cause this is a production environment and don't have a test one...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
We have to match both the env in this way

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/assets/.* asset
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/cron/.* cron
CustomLog /var/log/apache/assets.log common env=asset
CustomLog /var/log/apache/cron.log common env=cron
CustomLog /var/log/apache/access.log combined "expr=reqenv('asset_path') != 1 && reqenv('cron_mail') != 1"
```

That's because we have to get the values of the 2 env vars to check if BOTH are unset. When we set them with SetEnvIf we use the form "set the variable to 1 if the Request_URI match", so we have to use "requenv" and use integer comparison (negated)